# Why he has gone? Or why has he gone?

Tags: word-order, questions

> 1. Why **he has** gone?
> 2. Why **has he** gone?

Which is correct? Is there any difference or is it wrong? Many time I get confused which one to use.

Answer (score 1):

> Why has he gone?

is correct. While asking questions it's a general practice to flip the verbs like has and have.

For instance, a sentence such as "He has finished his homework." gets converted into a question "Has he finished his homework?". Notice, how I subtly interchanged the positions of "He has" and "Has he" to convert a statement into a question. A similar logic is at play in your case.

"He has gone." gets changed to "Has he gone?". But, we're more concerned about the reason why he has gone (because we already know that he has gone) and hence we just add a "why" and that makes the complete question: "Why has he gone?".

Comment: But you could say "Why he has gone is a mystery to me."  This is a statement rather than a question, so the words are in statement sequence, but it results in the first phrase being proper usage in a sentence (without the question mark).

Answer (score 0):

Why has he gone is the correct answer.
It's form of present perfect,
And it has a structure of question,
In present perfect you put has/have (according to the subject) after the Wh-word(i.e., why where how, etc)...
Happy learning,
Structure of present perfect in question form-
Wh-word + has/have + Subject + v3 + object ?
So putting info of your question in this structure we get -
Why + has + he + gone ???